# Unknown link added to my newly created wordpress website

Tags: php, wordpress, hyperlink

My newly created website www.skillplus.org catch in trouble of unwanted link at the left bottom corner with title "wordpress".

I also added screen-shot for the same. Please, visit and help me for the same.
[image]

Comment: That link redirects to a malware site...?

Answer (score 0):

It is a link putted by the free template, which leads to their website ; I can imagine they put it inside a `footer` template or something, but it is hard to help you without the theme code source.. Moreover, they probably have something like `legal mentions` that specify you have to keep this link.

Anyway, you should have the theme source if you use it ; as the link is not contained in a div, we can't really hide it with CSS. So you have to find manually which file of the theme is containing it, as I said it's probably a `footer.php` file. ;)

EDIT : after some search, I found [that topic](http://bestblackhatforum.com/Thread-GET-U-Design-2-1-0-2-0-1-WordPress-Theme?pid=467871#pid467871) ; it looks like they wrap it inside `functions.php`, in order to add it dinamically to the template and make the thing harder to remove. So try to remove the function named in my link, or another similar function. ;)